# IC to replace 4 FETs (switches)?

Tags: digital-logic, integrated-circuit, component-selection

I have 4 data lines that I want to put to high-Z if a pin (let's call it EN_OUT) is high (or low, if necessary), otherwise connect through.  I've successfully done that by putting an N-FET on each line (gate to EN_OUT).  For space considerations, I'd like to replace that with a logic IC that I'm sure exists... I'm just failing to figure out what it would be called :)

The closest I've come is a 4x1:1 de/mux like the NXP 74HC4066, which is fine but it has an enable pin for each circuit and is a tiny bit larger than I'd like.  I was hoping there'd be one with a single EN for all 4 circuits.

Can someone give me a nudge on what that would be called?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for but if it is simply a space problem then the smallest you will probably get is a simple tri-state buffer. Here is an example: http://www.ti.com/general/docs/lit/getliterature.tsp?genericPartNumber=dm54125&fileType=pdf
I have never personally used this model so do some more research before actually putting it in something but this is my nudge

Comment: To the OP, go to digikey and search for buffers. There are so many it will make your head spin. There are also FET bus switch products from TI and other which will work even for relatively high-speed signals. They are a slightly more sophisticated version of what you are already doing. Google quad FET bus switch, and I am sure you will find something from TI.

Comment: "buffer", thanks... that was the slap on the forehead I needed.  Cheers.  Still can't find a quad with a single OE for all four A/Y pairs, but at least there are enough hits that I should be able to find one with a small enough package.  I hope :)